# How can I group multiple plots and save them in png on Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to build a notebook for beginners as me, to plot the Google Gata Mobility Report, but I'm having trouble adjusting on a single image all the plots and save them on a single file. What can I do to get that output?

Here's the original code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
plt.style.use('seaborn-poster')

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
gmr_df = pd.read_csv ('https://www.gstatic.com/covid19/mobility/Global_Mobility_Report.csv')

# Categorías disponibles en el reporte de Movilidad de Google.
categories_google_mobility = ['retail_and_recreation_percent_change_from_baseline',
'grocery_and_pharmacy_percent_change_from_baseline',
'parks_percent_change_from_baseline',
'transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline',
'workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline',
'residential_percent_change_from_baseline']
categories_google_mobility

# Selecciona el país y la región.
country = 'Mexico'
region = 'Colima'
sub_df = gmr_df[(gmr_df['country_region']== country) & (gmr_df['sub_region_1']==region)]
sub_df.loc[:,'date'] = pd.to_datetime(sub_df.loc[:,'date'])
sub_df = sub_df.sort_values('date', ascending=True)

# Con esto puedes comenzar  a visualizar las series de tiempo del reporte de Google
for group in categories_google_mobility:
 print(group)
  
 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 4))
 plt.plot(sub_df['date'], sub_df[group], label=group)
 #La siguiente línea, dibuja una línea horizontal con el valor base (0).
 ax.axhline(y=0, color='gray')
 #Las siguientes dos líneas de código (ax.axvline) son contextuales. En este caso, la primera marcará una línea vertical color rojo en el 18 de marzo; corresponde a la Declaratoria de Emergencia en el estado de Colima. La segunda, con fecha del primero de junio, alude al inicio de la Nueva Normalidad en el país. 
 ax.axvline(pd.to_datetime('2020-03-18'), color='r', linestyle='--', lw=2)
 ax.axvline(pd.to_datetime('2020-06-01'), color='g', linestyle='--', lw=2)
 plt.title(country + ' '+ region + ': ' + group)
 plt.tight_layout()
 plt.grid()
 plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?  If so, you were very close.  The `subplots` command allows you to set a grid of axes within the figure that are contained in a numpy array.  Then instead of `plt.plot` you use `ax.plot`, and so forth for setting properties.

```py
# Con esto puedes comenzar  a visualizar las series de tiempo del reporte de Google
n = len(categories_google_mobility)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(n, 1, figsize=(16, 4 * n))

for group, ax in zip(categories_google_mobility, axes):
    print(group)
    ax.plot(sub_df['date'], sub_df[group], label=group)
    #La siguiente línea, dibuja una línea horizontal con el valor base (0).
    ax.axhline(y=0, color='gray')
    #Las siguientes dos líneas de código (ax.axvline) son contextuales. En este caso, la primera marcará una línea vertical color rojo en el 18 de marzo; corresponde a la Declaratoria de Emergencia en el estado de Colima. La segunda, con fecha del primero de junio, alude al inicio de la Nueva Normalidad en el país. 
    ax.axvline(pd.to_datetime('2020-03-18'), color='r', linestyle='--', lw=2)
    ax.axvline(pd.to_datetime('2020-06-01'), color='g', linestyle='--', lw=2)
    ax.set_title(country + ' '+ region + ': ' + group)
    ax.grid(True)
    
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig("plot.png")
```

[image]